# Child Collection View Delegate Methods are not called From Parent tableView when TableView Cells are scrolling in Upward Direction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

My scenario is:
I have a tableView and Inside of tableView a CollectionView is present.

**Working Properly in case:** When I am scrolling tableView top to bottom, child collectionView Delegate Methods are getting called.

**Not Working case:** When I am scrolling table View Bottom to Up, Child collection View Delegate methods are not getting called.

I am not sure why delegate methods are not getting called while scrolling tableView Bottom to Up.

Below is My code for settingUp delegates for CollectionView:

ProductListCell is the name of my tableViewCell.

```
extension ProductListCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource & JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        CalenderCollectionView.calendarDelegate = dataSourceDelegate
        CalenderCollectionView.calendarDataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        CalenderCollectionView.tag = row
        CalenderCollectionView.setContentOffset(CalenderCollectionView.contentOffset, animated:false)
        CalenderCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
        set { CalenderCollectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue }
        get { return CalenderCollectionView.contentOffset.x }
    }
}
```

Required TableView Methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("will display cell")
    if((indexPath.row+1)/10 == self.pageNumber && self.pageNumber < self.TotalPages){
        self.pageNumber+=1
        self.ApiCallforCategoryData()
    }

    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? ProductListCell else { return }
    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("did end displaying cell")
    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? ProductListCell else { return }
    storedOffsets[indexPath.row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset
}
```

Give me some clarity over how it will work or why its working currently like this. Let me know If i need to add more code.

Comment: try to put **tableViewCell.CalenderCollectionView.reloadData()** after line **tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0** in **willDisplayCell**

Comment: There is no effect after putting this line. @Sh_Khan

Comment: I think `prepareForReuse` is better candidate for reloading `collectionView` and setting `delegate` etc

Comment: @Kamran I placed reloadData() in prepareForReuse . It worked perfectly.Thanks